# Rexx, Parse a file for a single line

Tags: rexx

I'm trying to find a way to parse a file in Rexx. Each line has two words and an IP address.
Example
Location Name 10.0.0.1

I have looked over a lot of documentation and i can get it to print all the lines in the file but i cannot figure out how to search an entire file and print a specific line by using a match operator.

Comment: Which version of Rexx are you using ZOs, Regina etc. What sort of match are you trying to do ??.

Comment: I'm not totally sure on which version its, Rexx Scripting through a program called ZOC, "http://www.emtec.com/zoc/documents.html". Their documentation reference says "Regina Rexx" Version 3.4 not sure if that helps. Basically i want to run a match on the first column and and if possible return all 3 values on the match line as variables.

Answer (score 1):

For **Regina Rexx** this is a program should be close to what you want:

```
   Call A000_init

   Call R000_ReadFile
   do while MoreData
       parse var line pt1 pt2
       if (pt1 == whatever) then do
           /* Do some thing */              
       end
       Call R000_ReadFile
   end


A000_init:
        Yes      = 1
        No       = 0
        MoreData = yes
        filename = .....
return



R000_ReadFile:

    if lines(filename,'N') then do
       Line= LineIn(filename)
    end; else do
       line = ''
       MoreData = no
    end
Return
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty easy task for a Rexx program.

```
ExpectedLocation = 'Living Room'          /* What location are we searching for? */
Signal on NotReady                        /* Jump to "NotReady:" at end-of-file. */
Do Forever                                /* ... or at least until EOF or Exit! */
   Parse LineIn Word1 Word2 IPAddress .   /* Pull apart the three tokens on the line */
   Location = Word1 Word2                 /* Put the two words of the location back together. */
   If Location = ExpectedLocation then Do /* Did we find it? */
      Say "Found it :-)"                  /* Yay! */
      Exit                                /* We're done, stop the program. */
   End
End
NotReady:                                 /* We come here at end-of-file. */
Say "Didn't find it :-("                  /* Darn! */
```

Regina is Open Source, the project is on SourceForge at http://regina-rexx.sourceforge.net, and the documentation for the version you're using can be downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/regina-rexx/files/regina-documentation/3.4/

Comment: Looks like what i need though how to i define which file to look at?

Comment: As written, this will read from the standard input stream (like any other console-mode program).  But you can replace the `Parse LineIn ...whatever...` with `InputLine = LineIn("whatever_file.txt")` and `Parse var InputLine with ...whatever...` and it will read "whatever_file.txt" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Input file :  XXXXXX.XXXX.XXXX

```html
***************************** Top of Data
Location1 Name1 11.11.11.11
Location2 Name2 22.22.22.22
Location3 Name3 33.33.33.33
**************************** Bottom of Data
```

Code:

```html
/* REXX                                                                        */
/* Author : Ebin Paulose                                                       */
/*=============================================================================*/
YourWord = Location2  /*Word which we need to find, here i m giving "Location2"*/
Your_PS = 'XXXXXX.XXXX.XXXX'               /*File name where we need to search */
"ALLOC DA('"Your_PS"') F(FILEDD) SHR REUSE" /* Allocate the file               */
DO FOREVER                                                              
"EXECIO 1 DISKR FILEDD"                                             
    IF RC>0 THEN LEAVE                                                  
    PULL Record                             /* pull one record from file      */
    PARSE VAR Record Location  " " Name " " IPAddress  
                   /* parse record into  3 parts Location, Name and IPAddress */
    IF Location   = YourWord  THEN do      /* check for matching              */
       SAY 'Found : ' Location                                          
       Found = 'Y'                                                      
    END                                                                 
END                                                                     
IF Found ¬= 'Y' THEN DO                                                 
   SAY 'Sorry Search item Not found'                                    
END                                
"EXECIO 0 DISKR FILEDD (FINIS"     
"FREE F(FILEDD)"
```

Output 1 (item found) :
Found :  LOCATION2

---

Output 2 (item not found) :
Sorry Search item Not found

---

Answer (score 0):

```
filename = 'MY.DATA.SET'
if sysdsn(''''filename'''') <> 'OK' then exit

address 'TSO'
"ALLOCATE FILE(INDD) DATASET('"filename"') SHR REUSE"
"EXECIO DISKR * INDD(STEM file. FINIS)"
"CLOSE FILE(INDD)"

target = 'My Location'
found = 1==0 /* false */
do i = 1 to file.0
  card = file.i
  parse var card loc1 loc2 ip_address .
  found = loc1' 'loc2 == target
  if found then leave
  end i
if found then
  say 'IP address of 'target' is 'ip_address
else
  say 'No IP address found for 'target

exit
```